# TypeScript throws "File is not a module" error on d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have old JS code which I want to use in TypeScript.

Consider my files:

**webapiClient/index.js**

```
module.exports = require("./rest");
```

**webapiClient/index.d.ts**

```
declare module "webapiClient" {
    class Rest {

        constructor(cfg?:{
            prefix?: string;
            batchGetRequests?: boolean
        });

        prefix: string;
        setCfg(updatedCfgParams: {[key: string]: any}): void;
        get<T>(path: string, params?:any, options?:any): Promise<T>;
        post<T>(path: string, bodyObject?:any): Promise<T>;
        put<T>(path: string, bodyObject?:any): Promise<T>;
        remove<T>(path: string, bodyObject?:any): Promise<T>;
        param(v:any):any;
        processBatch(param:any, options?:any):Promise<any>;
        getUrlParams(url:string, toLower?:boolean):Object;
        getUrlParam(url:string, p:string):Object;
        getUrl(path:string, query?:any):string;
        getPath(path:string, query?:any):string;
        many(ref, p):any;
    }

    export = Rest;
}
```

I import my module using this code:

`import webClient = require("../webapiClient");`

But when I build my porject with webpack, I get an error:

`error TS2306: File 'path/to/webapiClient/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

What's wrong?